# How to write a bash completion to complete director names starting at ~/

Tags: bash, scripts

Imagine I have a bash script called `myscript` that will only `echo` it's first argument, which will be a directory name.
Example of usage:
`myscript proj1`
Where `proj1` is a directory for example located at `~/folder1/folder2/proj1` and your current working directory is `~/`.
My question is, for this script how could I write a completion rule so that `myscript [tab][tab]` would list all directories available to `echo`, starting at `~/`. This means that in the first example and assuming those are the only directories at `~/`, `myscript pro[tab]` would complete the expression to `myscript proj1`.
Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to be able to complete any subdirectory under ~, recursively

Comment: @glennjackman Yes that's what I want to do, I just don't know how to write that. Do you think you could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description seems odd: If you get just `proj1`, how do you know what its parent directory is?

Anyway, to give you what you asked for:

```
# for me, this takes a looooooong time [1]. Do it once and cache it
mapfile -t _all_dir_names < <( find ~ -type d -printf "%f\n" )

# the function you want completion for
myfunc () { echo hello world $*; }

# the completion function
complete_myfunc() {
    local dir cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=()
    for dir in "${_all_dir_names[@]}"; do
        if [[ $dir == "$cur"* ]]; then
            printf -v dir "%q" "$dir"      # protect whitespace in the dir name
            COMPREPLY+=("$dir")
        fi
    done
}

# registering the completion
complete -F complete_myfunc myfunc
```

[1]: 2 minutes, 66782 directories